# Python insert missing elements in array

Tags: python, arrays, tuples, missing-data

I have an array in the following format:

```
[(u'iapsetting', 0), (u'iap-mms',0)]
```

The array must contain only tuples of this type:

```
(u'mmssetting', 0) or (u'iapsetting', 0) or (u'iap-mms', 0)
```

My first array is obviously missing the (u'mmssetting',0) but it could many different combinations of missing/existing tuples.

I am struggling to find a way to add the correct missing tuples. The array must always contain only 3 tuples.

This is what I have so far but it is not working as expected:

```
    for type in setup: #setup is the array containing 1,2 or 3 tuples

       iap_found = False
       mms_found = False
       iap_mms_found = False

       if type[0]=='iapsetting':
              iap_found = True

       elif type[0]=='mmssetting':
              mms_found = True
       elif type[0]== 'iap-mms':
              iap_mms_found = True
       #Add missing settings

       if(iap_found==False):
          print("MISSING IAP",setup)
          setup.append((u'iapsetting',0))

       elif(mms_found==False):
          print("MISSING MMS",setup)
          setup.append((u'mmssetting',0))
       elif(iap_mms_found==False):
          print("MISSING IAP-MMS",setup)
          setup.append((u'iap-mms',0))
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated because there might be a much better way of doing this. Thank you.

Sara

Comment: What exactly is not working as expected?

Comment: You should change all your `elif`s to `if`s, otherwise it will only check for 1 missing element, but what if 2 or 3 are missing?

Comment: You should really consider using a `dict` for this. It's *especially* suited for storing name-value pairs. It makes finding entries much more direct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
existing = set(x[0] for x in setup)
for expected in ('iapsetting', 'mmssetting', 'iap-mms'):
    if expected not in existing:
        setup.append((expected, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you were doing wrong were mainly two things:

- you initialized the flags inside the loop.
- you started adding missing settings before you finished looping through the whole array.

  ```
  # Initialize flags before entering loop:
  iap_found = False
  mms_found = False
  iap_mms_found = False

  for type in setup: #setup is the array containing 1,2 or 3 tuples
     if type[0]=='iapsetting':
         iap_found = True
     elif type[0]=='mmssetting':
         mms_found = True
     elif type[0]== 'iap-mms':
         iap_mms_found = True

  #Add missing settings after looping through the whole array: 

  if(iap_found==False):
     print("MISSING IAP",setup)
     setup.append((u'iapsetting',0))

  if(mms_found==False):
     print("MISSING MMS",setup)
     setup.append((u'mmssetting',0))
  if(iap_mms_found==False):
     print("MISSING IAP-MMS",setup)
     setup.append((u'iap-mms',0))
  ```

Comment: Thank you SiggiSv  ! This worked great ! You have a cake from me ! ;P (virtualcake)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `if` ... `elif` .. `elif` you should use

```
if not iap_found:
          print("MISSING IAP",setup)
          setup.append((u'iapsetting',0))
if not mms_found:
          print("MISSING MMS",setup)
          setup.append((u'mmssetting',0))
if not iap_mms_found==False:
          print("MISSING IAP-MMS",setup) 
          setup.append((u'iap-mms',0))
```

The problem of `if` .. `elif` is that only one branch will get executed.

For other solutions, different (and in this case also better) than `if`, see the other anwers

Answer (score 0):

I think sets represent this logic most clearly. Use a set comprehension to extract the strings.

```
 REQUIRED_VALUES = {"mmssetting", "iapsetting", "iap-mms"}
 input_tuple_list = [(u'mmssetting', 1), (u'iap-mms', 3)]

 # set comprehension paired with set difference -- results in {"iapsetting"}
 missing_values = REQUIRED_VALUES - {val for val, count in input_tuple_list}

 # results in [(u'mmssetting', 1), (u'iap-mms', 3), (u'iapsetting', 3)]
 input_tuple_list.extend((val, 0) for val in missing_values)
```

Comment: It's probably safe to assume that the integer elements of the tuples won't always be zero. Thus, sets of tuples won't work.

Comment: Yes, the integer is not always 0 :) but Thank you ! :)

Comment: @user4554133 I maintain that sets are the best way to handle this. Please see the update.

Comment: Looks good. I'd drop the original code and go with just the new stuff. (No need to mark it as an "update," either. The site's wiki features take care of that.)